# Facebook emoticons

Tags: facebook

Someone sent me this message in Facebook:

[image]

How did he make these emoticons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops I found it, there are many websites that provide it, [here](http://www.famoticons.com/) is an example.

Comment: I suggest marking your answer as approved if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't up/downvote or give comments yet because my rep isn't enough, but I'd just like to say that the link that @Shimmy gave provides only the basic emoticons Facebook has as shown on web and some codes **not** even used on Fb (like `[[f9.cash]]`).

@dw1's answer provided the complete list.

I'm using this [site](http://www.piliapp.com/facebook-symbols/) but it doesn't have descriptions per emoji. It has a neater UI though compared to the site answered by @dw1.

If you're on Messenger, you can easily see all emojis without looking for an external site to give you the list.

Answer (score 0):

The most complete site I've found is [fbicons.net](http://fbicons.net)